# Do Explicit Deny ACLs apply to a Domain Administrator account?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, access-control-list

I've had a need come in a client with a two way trust (source company doesn't want us to have full admin rights, so we're having lots of permissions issues).

We effectively need Domain Admin rights but only for a single OU.

- What happens if I place an account in the Domain Admin Security Group, then apply explicit deny permissions for all other OUs?
- Can a Domain Admin even be affected by explicit denys?

Comment: What is the output of the following command: NETDOM TRUST <trusting domain> /d:<trusted domain> /quarantine

Answer (score 5):

Explicit deny permissions always take precedence over explicit or inherited grant permissions, so, yes, a deny will do what you ask; however, an user with effective administrative rights will be able to forcibly change those permissions by taking ownership of objects and resetting ACLs, so a deny will only block an administrative user as long as he/she doesn't want to actually fight it.

Case in point: in Exchange environments, the "Domain Admins" and "Enterprise Admins" groups have an explicity deny ACL for "Receive As" and "Send As" permissions on all user objects, so that administrative users can't open other people's mailboxes; however, being administrative users, they can remove those permissions whenever they want, and are thus perfectly able to open any mailbox, if they really want to.

A much simpler and effective approach would be to not give administrative rights to the user account, but to give it Full Control permissions on the OU it will manage and on all of its child objects.

---

BTW, you can't place an external user account from a trusted domain in a domain global group such as "Domain Admins"; you can only place it in a domain local group such as "Administrators", or in a local group on member computers.

Comment: Thank you Massimo.  For our testing, Full Control on an OU didn't seem to be sufficient for this task to complete, thus the need for us to have Domain Admin Rights.  I ran my own test in a lab and was able to verify that you are correct.  So, suprisingly, even a Domain Admin can have rights restricted.  However, it seems that if someone is crafty enough, they could work around it.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of having administrative rights: being able to circumvent all the restrictions which apply to everyone else ;)

Comment: Re: your issue: you should analyze why Full Control on the OU is not enough for your needs and what access rights you are missing for what you're trying to do, then only grant those rights; for example, if you want to place an user from an OU on which you have Full Control in a group from another OU which you don't manage, this would fail because you need rights on both the user and the group objects.

Comment: Additionally consider management (vs. trying to get security just with technology): Administrators elevating their own permissions should immediately generate an audit event (either by changing the audit rules themselves or by attempting an audited action), which should initiate a review.